# Can't open Google Maps Activity. Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm trying to open Google Maps Activity from my Android app and then when i'm clicking on map, getting location.
But I can't open my Google Maps Activity.
Here is my code where i'm trying to open Activity:

```
    public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button buttonPlaceBD,buttonCurrPlace;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
        buttonPlaceBD=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPlaceBD);
        buttonPlaceBD.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonCurrPlace=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCurrPlace);
        buttonCurrPlace.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent;
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.buttonPlaceBD:
                intent=new Intent(this,BDMapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonBack:
                finish();
                break;
        }


    }
}
```

Here is my BDMapsActivity.java

```
public class BDMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener{

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bdmaps);
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;   
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
System.out.println("CLIIIIIIIIIICK: "+latLng);
    }
}
```

And here is my activity_bdmaps.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.serg_shapoval.astrologyes.BDMapsActivity" />
```

It gives me an error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                          Process: com.example.serg_shapoval.astrologyes, PID: 18731
>                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.serg_shapoval.astrologyes/com.example.serg_shapoval.astrologyes.BDMapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2221)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                              at com.example.serg_shapoval.astrologyes.BDMapsActivity.onCreate(BDMapsActivity.java:22)
>                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
>                                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Move         mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this); down to onMapReady()

Comment: @DanielNugent, thanx for an answer. It loading me Google Map Activity but it doesn't work onMapClick method!

Comment: You also need to get the SupportMapFragment and call `supportMapFragment.getMapAync(this);`

Comment: @DanielNugent, thanx! it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until `mMap` is not null and assigned to a valid reference before you dereference it.

Also, you're missing the call to `getMapAsync()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bdmaps);

    //Added:
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap; 
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this); //moved  
}
```